# Recognition of achievements over time

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, united-states

I am applying to a university in the US. In the online application, they've asked about:

> Additional Educational Experiences; Which of the following have you had experiences in? (select all that apply).

In a sub-section, they've asked to explain:

> Recognition of achievements over time.

What is it exactly? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks @MorganRodgers for the comment, I edited the question.

Comment: How do we know your achievements?

Comment: Thanks @scaaahu for the comment. My question is about "Recognition of achievements over time". Should I just list my academic achievements in application or they are asking about other something else?

Comment: @MorganRodgers, that is probably the correct answer.